# How do I search users on specific area from google map?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-maps

I have many users with their lat, long in the node js server with mongodb.

Now i'll enter a location say New York. and it will convert to lat lng via the geocode api and search within let's say 10 miles radius. Now I want to find out which users lat lng match within that area. How do i do this part?

Sorry for bad english.

Comment: so basically you want to know the area based on lat and lng ?

Comment: Did you consider putting markers on map based on the location of the people?

Comment: @ZiyaERKOC yes  I did. I updated the description. please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you got the location of the New York by geocoding. Since you have coordinates of the user, you can basically compare those location with that of New York by simple geometry and math skill.
Let `userLat` be the latitude of user and `userLng` be the longitude of the user. And also `yorkLat` and `yorkLng` are the coordinates of the new york. You could basically set up the following equation:

```
locationDiff = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(yorkLng - userLng, 2) + Math.pow(yorkLat - userLat, 2)
//You could modify inside the if condition to make sure they both have the same unit
if(locationDiff <= 100000){
   //This user is within the circle whose center is New York location and radius you provided
}
```